# use tf.nn.dynamic_rnn but final state don't have c and h

Tags: tensorflow, recurrent-neural-network, tensor

I'm working with tensorflow, I want run a program with RNN, but I got the followed error:

```
a=self._encoder_final_state[0].c
AttributeError: 'Tensor' object has no attribute 'c'
```

the program is like this:

```
self._encoder_cells = build_rnn_layers(
    cell_type=self._hparams.cell_type,
    num_units_per_layer=self._num_units_per_layer,
    use_dropout=self._hparams.use_dropout,
    dropout_probability=self._hparams.dropout_probability,
    mode=self._mode,
    residual_connections=self._hparams.residual_encoder,
    highway_connections=self._hparams.highway_encoder,
    dtype=self._hparams.dtype,
)

self._encoder_outputs, self._encoder_final_state = tf.nn.dynamic_rnn(
    cell=self._encoder_cells,
    inputs=encoder_inputs,
    sequence_length=self._inputs_len,
    parallel_iterations=self._hparams.batch_size[0 if self._mode == 'train' else 1],
    swap_memory=False,
    dtype=self._hparams.dtype,
    scope=scope,
)
a=self._encoder_final_state[0].c
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the [docs](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/nn/dynamic_rnn) of `dynamic_rnn`:

> If cells are `LSTMCells` `state` will be a tuple containing a
>   `LSTMStateTuple` for each cell.

And [here](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r1.13/api_docs/python/tf/nn/rnn_cell/LSTMStateTuple?hl=en) you can see that indeed `LSTMStateTuple` are the ones having the desired `c` and `h` properties.

Unfortunately, your code doesn't give me any clue what kind of cells you are using, but apparently, they are no `LSTMCells`. So I cannot give you any better advise than to switch to `LSTMCells`.